# One variable equation on real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, real-numbers

Find the real solutions of the following equation
$$\frac{4x-1}{x^2-2x+2}+\frac{4x+7}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac{4(2x+3)}{x^2+2}.$$

I think the problem was given in a junior olympiad.

My best idea was to denote $x-1=a$, $x+1=b$ and after adding $2$ the LHS becomes

$$\frac{(a+2)^2}{a^2+1}+\frac{(b+2)^2}{b^2+1}$$

which looks like a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good form for the RHS.

I also tried $x^2-2x+2=a$, $x^2+2x+2=b$ which leads to a somewhat nice looking

$$\frac{b-1}{a}+\frac{7-a}{b}=\frac{4(b-a+6)}{a+b}$$

but the computations are not nice.

By plotting, there are four solutions among which are $\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Are you sure that it is $4(2x+3)$ and not $2(4x+3)$? For in the latter case, there is a really nice solution.

Comment: Maybe it was a typo. What’s the idea behind your solution?

Comment: @JohnWK if $\frac ac +\frac bd = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$, then $\frac ac = \frac bd = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$, assuming none of the denominators is 0.

Comment: @DS: There is a factor of $2$ (should be $\frac ac+\frac bd=2\frac{a+b}{c+d}$), but still the computation is pretty neat.

Comment: yes, @ultralegend5385 I had typed that in a hurry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By multiplying with a common denominator the equation is equivalent to
$$
- 3x^4 + 8x^3 + 12x^2 - 16x - 12=0
$$
By writing it as $-(3x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and comparing coefficients we see that
this is just
$$
(3x^2 - 8x - 6)(x^2 - 2)=0.
$$
This gives four real solutions.